# Aurelia: Bindable property gets set "too late"

Tags: aurelia

In my custom element I have a bindable property "menu" which gets set from outside. My problem is that the "dish" properties which rely on the menu get queried before the menu property is set (so menu is undefined and the dishes can't be retrieved). What can I do here?

**menu-control.ts:**

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

import { Menu } from '../../../app/model/menu';
import { Dish } from '../../../app/model/dish';

export class MenuControl {

    @bindable menu: Menu;

    get dish1() {
        return this.getDish(1);
    }

    get dish2() {
        return this.getDish(2);
    }

    get dish3() {
        return this.getDish(3);
    }

    getDish(dishNo: number) {
        return this.menu.dishes.find(x => x.dishNo == dishNo);
    }
}
```

**menu-control.html:**

```
<require from="../dish-control/dish-control"></require>

<div class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 800px;">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left: 0;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left: 0;">
                <label>Vegetarisch</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Men&uuml; 1</h4><dish-control dish.bind="dish1"></dish-control>
        <h4>Men&uuml; 2</h4><dish-control dish.bind="dish2"></dish-control>
        <h4>Men&uuml; 3</h4><dish-control dish.bind="dish3"></dish-control>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to put an `if.bind="menu && menu.dishes"` on any of the parent componenets to the `<dish-control>`, or even the `<dish-control>` itself. This way the `<dish-control>` won't be be attached to the DOM and initialize itself until `this.menu.dishes` exists.